# compass utf-8 Chinese encoding

Tags: css, sass, compass

I have a legacy compass over sass setup. 
I need to add some Chinese fonts. And when compass is compiling .scss to .css it does not encode correctly Chinese characters. 
e.g. for "微軟正黑體" I get "σ╛«Φ╗ƒµ¡úΘ╗æΘ½ö".

What I have already done: 
1. Addded @charset "UTF-8" to the roof of scss. 
2. Added Encoding.default_external = 'utf-8' and encoding = 'utf-8' to config.rb.

Did not help. Anybody had this problem before?
Thank you,

Comment: Is your file `utf-8` encoded?

Comment: lol, thank you very much. This was the problem.  It was actually encoded in ANSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer to accept*

Usually when you copy-paste string to file that is non-`utf-8` encoded it gets wrongly re-coded to source encoding.

So as you say - you copy utf8 string and paste it to ANSII encoded file, so utf8 is *magically* converted to ANSII by editor and non-Latin symbols gets ruined

Comment: I'm using WebStorm so the files weren't UTF-8 encoded but I had no problems with displaying Chinese characters. Anyway I just saved the file as UTF-8.
Thanks.